# glassfish v3 and java EE in production mode: what are the options to update a live web app?

Tags: glassfish, java

I am building a web app using java EE and glassfish v3. I want to move it to production mode soon, however i have zero experience with using glassfish in production, i would appreciate if you give me some guidance about how to approach the following scenario:

say i have deployed the web app using admin console pointing to the .war file. But what if i want to update this live application, do i need to :

a) undeploy --> build new war file (with updates) --> paste the war file to the app folder -->redeploy?

b) move in only the changed files , ie : .class files , jsp, etc... without undeploying before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use a maven plugin and a tool similar to jenkins to do my deploys to production but you can always do it by hand like this:

1. Open the admin console (by default it's bound to port 4848)
2. Choose "Applications" on the menu
3. Next to the application you want to redeploy there should be a link labeled "Redeploy", click it.
4. Choose new war (and options related to precompiling jsp's and stuff)
5. Press OK

The new version of the application should be deployed after this process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx a lot. Two questions:1- is it more efficient to use maven or do it manually? or is it the same?. 2- I read some articles online that redeploy leaks some old sessions , is this true?

Comment: 1) It's just as efficient. What the maven plugin does is use the command line version of what I just sent you. The advantage for us is to have a central place where the team can run build/deploy jobs for the development and production environments.

Comment: 2) I know there are some classloader leaks that lead to OOM on the PermGen memory area but I'm not sure if they're directly related to Glassfish or commonly used libraries or just circular references that keep the GC from unloading those classes. Don't know what you mean about session leaks but one of the reasons to use redeploy instead of undeploy/deploy is being able to keep the schedulers and sessions from the previous deploy untouched (if you choose to do so).

Comment: Found these links where you can read more about classloader leaks and how to track and fix them http://frankkieviet.blogspot.pt/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html http://frankkieviet.blogspot.pt/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html

Comment: thx a lot bro! much appreciated !